# GPS Coordinates come 0.0 when tested on Android phone

Tags: android, gps, coordinates

I have followed several guides here to get gps coordinates on my android app. When I test it on an android phone, it gives me 0.0 for latitude and longitude. I can't understand why this is happening, would be glad if someone can help me out here.

**Codes I'm using now:**

**This is my main Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
GPSTracker mGPS = new GPSTracker(this);

TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texts);
if(mGPS.canGetLocation ){
mGPS.getLocation();
text.setText("Lat"+mGPS.getLatitude()+"Lon"+mGPS.getLongitude());
}else{
    text.setText("Unabletofind");
    System.out.println("Unable");
   }
}
```

**Location Tracking Class**

```
public final class GPSTracker implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
public boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

/**
 * Function to get the user's current location
 * 
 * @return
 */
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        Log.v("isGPSEnabled", "=" + isGPSEnabled);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        Log.v("isNetworkEnabled", "=" + isNetworkEnabled);

        if (isGPSEnabled == false && isNetworkEnabled == false) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                location=null;
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                location=null;
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
 * app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * 
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I have tried few other ways too, but I keep getting 0.0 on the phone, and I can't seem to figure out why. I will be very grateful if anyone can help me out. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42864929/115145

Answer (score 1):

There are several good tutorials online for Android GPS. You can also take the free online course from Udacity that covers Google Maps and GPS.

You need to implement more than the location listener. You need to implement the callback listeners. In a GPS app your class declaration should look something like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
     GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
     GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
}
```

Now you will need to implement several new methods. Primarily the onConnected method and in the onConnected method you will need to add a check for permission.  Your onConnected method should look like below.

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        Location mLastLocation;

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Connected");

        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Permission granted for Location");
        } else {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Permission denied for Location");
        }

        // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                latOutPut.setText(Location.convert(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), Location.FORMAT_SECONDS));
                lonOutPut.setText(Location.convert(mLastLocation.getLongitude(), Location.FORMAT_SECONDS));
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, MainActivity.this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but still keep on getting 0.0. The app does access the Location service, but not getting coordinates.

Comment: The code works now for some reason but the location does not get updates, it just gets location one time. I'm trying to work with this without using the Google api client, but thanks a lot for considering it though!